# Learning WPF and MVVM - best approach for learning from scratch

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I've got about three years c# experience. I'd like to learn some WPF and the MVVM pattern.
There are a lot of links to articles on this site but I'm getting a little overwhelmed.
Would a sensible approach for a begginer to be forget mvvm for a while and just quickly learn a bit a of WPF, then come back to MVVM?

I had a leaf through [Application=Code+Markup - Charles Petzold](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Applications-Code-Markup-Presentation-Foundation/dp/0735619573/ref=sr_1_9?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1269898175&sr=8-9) in work today, it doesn't seem to mention MVVM (at least not in the index). I was pretty surprised by this as I thought MVVM was supposed to be the "lingua franca" of WPF?

Also I've just started working at a new company and they are using MVVM with WinForms, has anyone come across this before?

Can anyone recommend a book that will teach me both WPF and MVVM?

Comment: The MVVM pattern is a popular approach for simplifying and detangling WPF applications, but it's not the only one. I've found that TMTOWTDI (there's more than one way to do it) definitely applies to WPF.

Comment: This book is exactly what you need: "Learn WPF MVVM" https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01M365NCZ  It teaches you WPF in no time, and then introduces you to MVVM. Disclaimer: it's my book. :-) Good luck on your learning!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It depends on your experience.

I personally felt that this was a lacking area in MVVM discussions, which was what led me to write my series on [MVVM and WPF from a Windows Forms developer perspective.](http://reedcopsey.com/series/windows-forms-to-mvvm/)

I would not try to learn WPF without learning MVVM.  You'll end up trying to "unlearn" many aspects, as WPF really doesn't make sense, completely, until you understand the separation of presentation and logic that's pervasive throughout the architecture.  MVVM is really just extending this same separation into the application space.

As for "MVVM in Windows Forms" - a lot of people try to do this, but it's not really MVVM.  In order to do "MVVM" you need access to a richer form of data binding than Windows Forms provides.  "MVVM in Windows Forms" is really, typically, just Model-View-Presenter with a different name (riding the MVVM bandwagon, I'd guess), but not really the same as MVVM in WPF.

Comment: WPF without MVVM is bewildering and frustrating.  WPF with MVVM is liberating and exciting.

Comment: WPF really requires some form of separation of concerns or it just doesn't make sense...

Comment: Thanks for the series, I've been looking for decent Winforms->WPF information.

Comment: After reading a lot of useless info on MVVM, where everybody spoke about MVVM in an uncomprehensible theoretical way, your tutorial began to make light on my head. Thank you.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Do you have some kind of published version of your posted series? Its the kind of thing I think I would love to have as an offline reference library

Comment: @eatumup No - but you're welcome to print them if you want.

Answer (score 13):

[Jason Dolinger](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/2650) has an excellent video on the subject. It steps you through the process moving from using code behind files to a full MVVM pattern including Dependency Injection and Testing.

[Bill Steele](http://blogs.msdn.com/wsteele) did a 16 part "Soup-to-Nuts" webcast series on WPF. The links on the msevents site are broken. Here is a [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22WPF+Soup+to+Nuts%3A%22+site%3Ablogs.msdn.com%2Fwsteele) to find them.  This will help with the WPF learning curve.  And he does NOT use any MV* patterns in his examples.

EDIT:  The [MSEvents](https://msevents.microsoft.com/CUI/AdvancedSearch.aspx?culture=en-US#culture=en-US;advanced=true;pageNumber=1;sortKey=relevance;sortOrder=ASC;pageEvent=true;hdnInitialCount=1;startDate=08/01/2007;endDate=12/31/2008;kwdAny=;countryId=US;languageCode=en;audience=26;products=157;eventType=3;searchcontrol=yes;s=1) links are working now, I am leaving the [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22WPF+Soup+to+Nuts%3A%22+site%3Ablogs.msdn.com%2Fwsteele) as a backup.

[Josh Smith](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com) also has an excellent article [WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) on MSDN.

Herding Code: 
    Presentation Patterns with Jeremy Miller, Ward Bell, Rob Eisenberg and Glenn Block

- [Part 1](http://herdingcode.com/?p=208)
- [Part 2](http://herdingcode.com/?p=212)

MIX10:

- Laurent Bugnion [Understanding the
  Model-View-ViewModel Pattern](http://live.visitmix.com/MIX10/Sessions/EX14)
- Rob Eisenberg [Build Your Own MVVM Framework](http://live.visitmix.com/MIX10/Sessions/EX15)

And of course Reed Copsey's [MVVM articles](http://reedcopsey.com/tag/mvvm/) are worth a read as well.

Comment: that Jason Dolinger video is a great start.

Comment: Yes, the Jason Dolinger video is what finally kicked on the lightbulb for me.  Highly recommended.

Comment: I loved to read part "process moving from using code behind files to a full MVVM pattern" this is what I'm needed..

Comment: Could you update the link of Jason Dolinger? Is it this video what you mean: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRxnZahCPFQ

Answer (score 6):

I was told a few times that my MIX10 session was explaining the MVVM pattern well enough for beginners (even though some parts are actually quite advanced, so don't worry if you need to re-watch certain parts).

The session is at http://live.visitmix.com/MIX10/Sessions/EX14

Sorry for the self-promotion.

Cheers,
Laurent

Comment: @Laurent: I missed that self-promotion before I added your session to my answer. :)

Comment: +1 I found your techdays video on mvvm very helpful! =) http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/kreekman/TechDays-2010-Understanding-the-Model-View-ViewModel-pattern

Answer (score 4):

There aren't many books covering MVVM but there is one : [Advanced MVVM](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/advanced-mvvm/)

But there are lots of online resources and this one is a must read : [WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

After that I suggest looking into frameworks like

- [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/getstarted/)
- [Caliburn](http://caliburn.codeplex.com/)

Comment: +1 when playing with WPF and MVVM last weekend, I almost immediately ran into the limitation that I couldn't bind event handlers to the viewmodel. The frameworks you link to appear to fix that, so I'll definitely be checking them out!

Answer (score 2):

To do big things (like learning WPF + MVVM) it is better to break the task in smaller steps.

I think that the best approach in this situation is to start by learning the UI part of Wpf. Learn XAML syntax, the layout system, the available controls and forget about binding and how to deliver data to the controls.

Once you know the UI basics of Wpf then it is time to move to MVVM. Learn how bindings work and the MVVM pattern.

In this Web you can find a tutorial focusing on the hands on but with the theory available:

http://www.learnmvvm.com

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm the author of the site I hope this is not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tutorial for MVVM http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819294/Learn-WPF-MVVM-step-by-step-Basics-to-Advance-Leve which goes from basic to the advance level in 5 steps. So its like graduating from a 3 layer to full MVVM.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this site. It collects the various resources at one place.
http://learnandmasterwpf.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

I just read this book. It is not really about learning WPF, but it should be useful once you already know a bit of WPF and want to progress your understanding of MVVM.

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Pro-WPF-Silverlight-MVVM-Model-View-ViewModel/dp/1430231629