# Learning WPF and Silverlight, from the beginning

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I am a C# programmar and now I want to learn WPF and silverlight.

Plz suggest me how should I proceed(from the very beginning) ?

and also some resources and books on it.

Comment: This is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405739/mvvm-tutorial-from-start-to-finish

Comment: Very related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438954/how-to-learn-wpf-are-their-any-specific-websites-for-them

Answer (score 3):

[Pro WPF and Silverlight MVVM - Gary Hall](http://www.silverlightbooks.net/book/wpf-silverlight-mvvm/)

Comment: That book has some terrible [reviews](http://www.amazon.com/Pro-WPF-Silverlight-MVVM-Model-View-ViewModel/dp/1430231629/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1301401524&sr=8-1)

Answer (score 1):

As always MSDN is our good friend.

And as Its already discussed on SO a **LOT** so, for links to some similar SO questions and answers look here

[Good resources for learning WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526150/good-resources-for-learning-wpf/1528018#1528018)

and this

[Learning WPF and MVVM - best approach for learning from scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541484/learning-wpf-and-mvvm-best-approach-for-learning-from-scratch)

Answer (score 0):

I learned Silverlight from this book: [http://www.amazon.com/Pro-Silverlight-4-Matthew-MacDonald/dp/1430229799](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430229799) and thought it was perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I put this together recently, it might help give you a high level view.

I'm looking for feedback on it, so I'll be hawking it around places ;)

[WPF class hierarchy diagram](http://kittencode.wordpress.com/2011/02/03/wpf-class-hierarchy-diagram/)

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight can be a bit easier for starting with "XAML technology", but if your main goal is to write apps for Windows (I mean desktop application) then I think you should go for WPF.

For learning Silverlight I always recommend [Silverlight 4 in Action](http://www.manning.com/pbrown/)

Answer (score 0):

Check the official: http://www.silverlight.net/

Here you can find large collection of getting started tutorials, videos, samples etc...

Answer (score 0):

For WPF you can use [WPF Unleashed](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672331195). It starts with the basic stuff and you'll end up learning everything you need to know. It's also quite useful just for references.